# Very ReactJS with PHP

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

Hi I have started to learn React JS but when I'm Starting to fetch API I'm getting an error:

> parsing failed SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

This is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

       <style type="text/css">
         body {
            background: #538cb5;  
          }
          .app-container {
            background: #fff; 
            max-width: 480px;
            margin: 60px auto;
            padding: 40px 25px;
          }

          h3 {
            color: #538cb5;
          }
          input {
            margin: 20px 0;
          }
       </style>

       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

       <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js' crossorigin></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js" crossorigin></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js" crossorigin></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js" crossorigin></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Data />
    }
  }

  class Data extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props) 
      this.state = {
        data : [
        {"play_slot_id":"227","playSlot":"E","date":"2018-10-06","time":"14:00","randValue":"683394","new_randValue":"","createdDate":"2018-10-06 13:26:30","updatedDate":"2018-10-06 13:26:30","status":"active"},{"play_slot_id":"227","playSlot":"E","date":"2018-10-06","time":"14:00","randValue":"683394","new_randValue":"","createdDate":"2018-10-06 13:26:30","updatedDate":"2018-10-06 13:26:30","status":"active"},{"play_slot_id":"227","playSlot":"E","date":"2018-10-06","time":"14:00","randValue":"683394","new_randValue":"","createdDate":"2018-10-06 13:26:30","updatedDate":"2018-10-06 13:26:30","status":"active"}
        ]
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      fetch('http://iqexpert.in/android_login_api/getRand.php',{mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((data) => { 
        console.log('parsed json', data)
        this.setState({data : data}) 
      })
      .catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      })
    }  

    render(){
      if(!this.state.data) return <p>Loading</p>

      var elements = this.state.data.map( (item,index) => {
        return <li key={item.id}>SLOT: {item.playSlot} | Random: {item.randValue}  </li>
      })
      console.log(elements)
      return <ol>{elements}</ol>
    }
  }    
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried with and without CDN but still getting the same errors in ReactJS. I have made API's for my Android Project. It is consumed properly in Android devices but I am not able to render properly in React JS.

Comment: Seems to work fine at https://jsfiddle.net/x3hp9ugw/1/ As far as the API cosumption, is you page being run by the same domain as the API ? otherwise you need to enable cors on the server.

Comment: No I'm consuming through ReactJS on Localhost

Comment: Then there is the problem. The server which provides the data is not CORS enabled and the browser does not allow CORS requests if the remote server does not allow it.

Comment: I added CORS on my Server Backend Code but still getting same error

Comment: the "iqexpert.in" server ?

Comment: Ok, now you just need to change `{mode: 'no-cors'}` to `{mode: 'cors'}` and make sure your localhost is run in http and not https

Comment: Yes its working thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how we should implement React components between script tags, but don`t you need to import React as **import React from 'react'**

```
<script type=text/babel>
   import React from 'react' // <<---- HERE 
   class App extends React.Component {
```

Comment: yes, It's not necessary when we are using CDN to import those componenet's. I also tried in React Native but also getting same error could you help me how to remove this error